# Nginx add sites

Tags: nginx

I am new to Nginx and webservers overall and I need some help to realise my dream.

Currently I store my htdocs in /srv/www/
I have one page on /srv/www/foo/public_html and another one at /srv/www/bar/public_html. 
The idea is that I want to reach them by visiting myip/foo and myip/bar.

Currently when I visit myip I'm being sent to /srv/www/foo/public_html which is something I found a bit wierd. I've looked around on "server blocks" but failed to understand and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

well if you're going to use only 1 IP, then it's 1 server block ( 1 virtual host )

```
server {
    server_name [domain name or ip];
    index index.html; # or php or whatever
    location /foo {
        root /var/www/foo/public_html;
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }
    location /bar {
        root /srv/www/bar/public_html;
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }
}
```

You haven't mentioned what kind of application this is, so it probably need some changes depending if its a php site or rails or any thing else, this would work for static content only like html and images.

Comment: Where do I enter this? It's a PHP site by the way.

Comment: do you have a folder called `/etc/nginx/sites-available` ?

Comment: Yes, I do ahve that one.

Comment: ok so create a new file in there, and call it whatever you want, and put the conf in my answer inside it, then go to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and create a symlink `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/[filename]` then restart nginx `sudo service nginx restart`